# View a picture in GWT HTML

Tags: gwt

I want to know how to view a picture in a HTML?

Example:

```
HTML htmlS = new HTML(picture resource+"[加载中...]");
```

how can I write "picture resource" GWT code?

Answer (score 3):

Create an object of `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image` and make a call to `setUrl()` with the URL of the image resource.

```
image.setUrl(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + <relative path to image resource>)
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it.

If for some reason it has to be HTML, use "<img src='path'>";

Answer (score 1):

You can use the img tag in HTML widget..